# Hibernate auto update table in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following configuration in my Spring MVC project:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tracDB"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-practice"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.paweljarosz.trac.data"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>

        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

I would like Hibernate to automatically create and update data model based on entities. Does anyone know how to fix this configutation to achieve it?

Comment: are you talking about `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you need something like this

```
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
      <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
      <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
      <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
   </bean>
</property>
```

Alternatively, most of these things can also be set in the JPA properties directly. Spring lets you do that through the `jpaVendorProperties` as well. See [Hibernate Configuration Properties](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional) for reference.

For example:

```
<property name="jpaProperties">
   <props>
     <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
       <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
       <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
       <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
       <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">100</prop>
       <!-- This one below is what you're looking for-->
       <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
  </props>
</property>
```